# Why is ionization energy measured in gaseous phase?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

When I looked up the definition of ionization energy, it says:-

> it is the energy required to remove one electron from the shell to
>   infinity in an atom in gaseous state.

Why is it measured in gaseous phase and not in any other phase?

Comment: You can define the energy necessary to remove an electron from a solid instead of a free atom/molecule, but it takes on another name, the [work function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_function). As expected the extra intermolecular interactions stabilize the material after losing an electron, and so it's much easier to remove an electron from a solid than a single atom/molecule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to determine the energy for a **single molecule** and avoid stabilization effects through intermolecular interactions.